# Entity Framework update from database doesn't show at my edmx file

Tags: c#, .net, database, visual-studio, entity-framework

After successful connection with database can't see tables. I try to use "Update from database" button but it doesn't appear at menu. How can fix it? What did i miss?

[image]

Comment: You missed the part "Right click on the design surface". You should double-click the EDMX in the solution explorer to open the design surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For view tables you have two options (Maybe more, I don't know):

1 - Double click in "edmx" file, it will show you a database diagram.

2 - Once inside the diagram open View --> Other Windows --> Entity explorer data model.

Inside new panel you can see a lot of information of your database, like tables and Views in "Tables/Views" or functions in "Functions/procedures".

[image: Ef show tables]

And for add, update database, inside edmx diagram, right click, "Update model from database" and you will be able to add, update or delete tables, views... etc:

[image: Ef update, add or remove items]

Comment: I did it, but any model hasn't been added. Didn't receive any error also.

Comment: You have to select tables that you want to add to the model by expanding and checking it !!! @SixtySeven Try and tell me please !!!

Comment: I select evey time but model still hasn't been created. I try to open toolbox but it's closing immediately.

Comment: I have sht like this: errors.EntityModels.edmx

Comment: Are you triying to add or to update tables?

Comment: Resolved. Primary key was missing. Thanks for your advices.

Comment: I'm glad to hear it. Welcome to StackOverflow !!!